# Does pointwise convergence imply boundedness?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

**Setting** We work on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F})_{t\in[0,T]},P)$. Let $(X^n)_n$ and $X$ be finite variation processes such that $X^n$ converges pointwise to $X$, i.e. $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X^n_t(\omega)=X_t(\omega)$$ for all $(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times[0,T]$, and such that $(\|X^n\|)^n$ converges pointwise to $\|X\|$ (where $\|\cdot\|_t$ denotes the total variation on $[0,t]$).

**Question** Does this imply that $\sup_n\|X^n\|<\infty$ pointwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the fact that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\|X^n\|)_n = \|X\| < \infty$ pointwise.  This implies there exists $N = N(\omega)$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $|\|X^n(\omega)\| - \|X(\omega)\|| < 1$.  Therefore $\|X^n(\omega)\| < 1 + \|X(\omega)\|$ for all $n \ge N$, and hence \begin{align*}
\sup_n \|X^n(\omega)\| &\le \sup_{n \le N} \|X^n(\omega)\| + \sup_{n \ge N} \|X^n(\omega)\| \\
&\le \sup_{n \le N} \|X^n(\omega)\| + 1 + \|X(\omega)\| < \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. In some literature "$X$ finite variation" means that the paths $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ are of finite variation *for almost each* $\omega\in\Omega \enspace (*)$. I think in your response you interpreted "$X$ finite variation" as that this holds for *each* $\omega$. However, if only $(*)$ holds, does you answer still work?

Comment: @hannah Yes, it still works.  Just let $E_n$ be the set (with $\mathbb{P}(E_n)=0$) on which $\|X^n(\omega)\| = \infty$, $E$ be the set with $\|X(\omega)\| = \infty$, and apply the proof to $\omega \not \in N := (\bigcup_n E_n) \cup E$.  Since $N$ is the countable union of null sets, $\mathbb{P}(N) = 0$ as well, so this still holds for a.e. $\omega$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "so this still holds for a.e. $\omega$"? My original question was if the result holds pointwise, i.e. for each $\omega$ and each $t$, i.e. I would like to understand if this still holds if we only assume $(*)$.

Comment: If $\|X(\omega)\| = \infty$ for some $\omega$, and $\|X^n(\omega)\| \rightarrow \|X(\omega)\|$ for all $\omega$, then we clearly won't have $\sup_n \|X^n(\omega)\| < \infty$ for those $\omega$ with $\|X(\omega)\| = \infty$.  And similarly, if $\|X^n(\omega)\| = \infty$ for some $n$ and $\omega$, then we also can't have $\sup_n \|X^n(\omega)\| < \infty$ for those $\omega$.  In general, you can't conclude things about all $\omega$ from properties that only hold for a.e. $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for these explanations. Just to clarify, if "$X$ finite variation" means that the paths are of finite variation for almost each $\omega$, then $\sup_n\|X^n\| <\infty$ a.s.. However, if "$X$ finite variation" means that this holds for each $\omega$, then $\sup_n\|X^n\| <\infty$ would hold pointwise. Is this correct?

Comment: @hannah Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you again!